# rJava Memory Error

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am building a large species distribution model using the package "dismo" in the latest version of r. When I go to process the basic model using the code:

```
me <- maxent(x=train, p=p)
```

I get the following error:

```
> Error in .jcall(mxe, "S", "fit", c("autorun", "-e", afn, "-o", dirout,
> :    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

There is some discussion in stackoverflow and the internet about this error but none seem to address how to resolve the issue in  the r code. Any input on this issue would be appreciated.

Cheers, 
Israel

Comment: I don't know about r and rjava, so I'm not sure how tje JVM is beiong run, but it must be if Java is running. The JVM can take parameters telling it how much memory to use. So, that may be a clue for you to look.

Comment: I had similar errors and I had to increase allocated memory using
> options(java.parameters = "-Xmx200m")

Comment: Worth noting that for the increase in memory to be effective it has to be done before the JVM in enabled: http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the `dismo` package:
If you want to give MaxEnt (the Java virtual machine that runs it) more memory, you can do that by
running something like this (for 1 GB) before you load the dismo library.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1g" )
```

Some people have reported problems when using this function on a Mac (Apple) computer. Specifically, the following error message occurs:

```
Error in .jcall(mxe, "S", "fit", c("autorun", "-e", afn, "-o", dirout, : java.lang.InternalError: Can’t start the AWT because
Java was started on the first thread. Make sure StartOnFirstThread is not specified in your application’s Info.plist or on the command line.
```

This is a known problem with certain Java applications on Macs. There are two work-arounds that we are aware of:

1) run Sys.setenv(NOAWT=TRUE) before running library rJava (this is what
dismo does if rJava is not loaded).
2) use the JGR interface (a Java based R GUI). You can install JGR from here: